# Question regarding batch apex salesforce

Tags: apex, batch

I am updating the contact information based on   another object activity   by comparing the contactid of the value. if the activity having multiple records i want to update the  contact with recent record created on activity object record.
In case of batch size 1 it is updating with recent value where as batch size of 50/100 it randomly updating the value.

```
global class Updatecontacts implements Database.Batchable<sObject>  {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        Datetime date_time = datetime.now().addhours(-4);

        string query = 'select Id,Contact__c,Attribute__c, Topic__c,Date__c from  Activity__c where Contact__c!=null and createddate >=: date_time' ;
        query+=' and Scoring_Attribute__c  like \'%' + 'Email Sent''%\'';
        //query+=' and createddate > d';

        system.debug(query + 'Mc activity data');   

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Activity__c> scope){

        if(scope.size()>0){
            Map<id,Activity__c>Mcamap=New  Map<id,Activity__c>();

            for(Activity__c mc:scope){
                Mcamap.put(mc.Contact__c,mc);

            }
            system.debug('Contact ids list'+ Mcamap);

            List<Contact> conlist= new List<Contact>([ select id,Email_Sent__c,Email_Sent_Date__c   from Contact where id iN :Mcamap.keyset()]); 

            List<Contact> conidlist= New list<Contact>();

            for(Contact con:conlist){
                id str=con.id;

                if(Mcamap.containskey(str) ){

                    con.Email_Sent__c=Mcamap.get(str).Topic__c;
                    con.Email_Sent_Date__c =Mcamap.get(str).Date__c;

                    conidlist.add(con);

                    system.debug('conidlist list of data'+conidlist);
                }
            }
            if(conidlist.size()>0){
                Update conidlist;
            }        
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use a code formatter such as Prettier or manually work in your IDE to ensure that your indentation, whitespace, and bracing is consistent. It is extremely difficult to read code that is jumbled all over the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify an "ORDER BY", the results are in an indeterminate order. By forcing the order of the records, the older values should be replaced by the newer values as the batch processes. Here's the change:

```
            ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
```

Your code is also twice as large as it needs to be. Here's an optimized version that explains all of the changes.

```
global class Updatecontacts implements Database.Batchable<sObject>  {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        Datetime date_time = datetime.now().addhours(-4);
        // Use inline queries unless you need dynamic fields or criteria.
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            select Id,Contact__c,Attribute__c, Topic__c,Date__c from  Activity__c where 
            Contact__c!=null and createddate >=:date_time and Scoring_Attribute__c  like '%Email Sent%'
            ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
        ]);

    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Activity__c> scope){
        Map<id,Activity__c>Mcamap= New  Map<id,Activity__c>();
        // Scope is always at least 1 element. No need for if(scope.size() > 0)
        for(Activity__c mc:scope) {
            Mcamap.put(mc.Contact__c,mc);
        }
        // The result of a query is already a list, no need to new List<...>(query)
        List<Contact> conlist = [select id,Email_Sent__c,Email_Sent_Date__c   from Contact where id iN :Mcamap.keyset()]; 
        // No need to copy the records to a new list as you update them.
        for(Contact con:conlist){
            // This contact is guaranteed to have an Activity__c record. No need to check map.containsKey(id);
            // No need for the temporary varible str.
            // Use "caching" instead of getting the record from the map each time.
            Activity__c act = Mcamap.get(con.Id);
            con.Email_Sent__c=act.Topic__c;
            con.Email_Sent_Date__c =act.Date__c;
        }
        // You are guaranteed to have something to update here.
        // Also, even if not, it is harmless to perform a DML on an empty list (no governor limits used)
        Update conlist;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and updated the code